# R Shiny: how to share url with required filters for an analysis

Tags: r, rest, url, shiny, shiny-server

I developed a Shiny app that I use to monitor some information
relevant to my company.

The app works fine but often if I notice something interesting in the data and I want to share it with my colleagues I have to send around an email
that says something on the lines of

> Go to http://shiny.company.com:3838/
>
> Select dates from "x" to "y"
>
> In field "z" select this choices
>
> and so on....

Clearly the best way would be to share a link that would make the Shiny app apply all the required settings.

I think I can partially solve the issue by using the function `parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)`
to set the relevant parameter from an url.

How I can update the url in the browser address bar when one selects values for the parameters? This way sharing a link becomes a matter of copying and pasting the address bar.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297489/accept-http-request-in-r-shiny-application

Comment: @nicola thanks for the suggestion. The answer seems to deal with receiving parameters from the url (which I do with parseQueryString). However so far I have not been able to update the url in the browser so that I can copy and paste it to share specific analyses.

Comment: check out the [shinyURL](https://github.com/aoles/shinyURL) package

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @daattali, you are welcome to have a look at the **[shinyURL](https://github.com/aoles/shinyURL)** package which provides functionality to generate bookmarkable URLs which can be used to easily share a particular view state of your app.

Check out the [live demo](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/shinyURL) to see the package in action.