# Does RStudio Shiny Server support RESTful

Tags: r, rest, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I looked at the http://shiny.rstudio.com, it looks to me that the shiny server is heavily bounded with shiny UI things. That is, the requests to shiny server could only be invoked via shiny ui widgets.

I would ask whether shiny server supports REST, so that I can use some rest client instead of shiny ui widget to directly call the api that shiny server provides, this would be very helpful for integration between different languages, like java calls R.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297489/accept-http-request-in-r-shiny-application

Comment: Currently no, but it is a feature being developed by the shiny team

Comment: Thanks @neilfws, I looked at the discussions there that the code is complex and not straightforward from REST's view. From REST's view, give me a resource url together with some request data, and the rest api will give you the result, nothing to do UI.

Comment: Thanks @Dean for the information.

Comment: If you want a REST API, you could try out Microsoft R's [R Server Operationalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/operationalize/about).

Comment: Thanks @HongOoi for the information. I would guess that the R Server you mentioned is commercial?

Comment: Yes, although if you have an MSDN account you can download a developer licensed edition for free.

Comment: Thanks @HongOoi for the information , i will try thanks

Comment: For future readers:  Please check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283736/r-shiny-rest-api-communication/71064046#71064046) which is showing how to handle POST requests directly in `shiny`.