# Receive push data in R Shiny application

Tags: python, r, get, shiny, shiny-server

I have a simple python program, which should push its data into an R Shiny application. These lines in Shiny parse the "GET" input:

```
  # Parse the GET query string
  output$queryText <- renderText({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    eventList[query$eventid] <<- query$event
  })
```

This works fine with a browser calling "http://127.0.0.1:5923/?eventid=1223&event=somestring". If I try to call the URL in python I get a "Connection reset by peer" in R and nothing is added to the list. My Python code so far:

```
request = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1:5923/?eventid=1223&event=somestring")
test = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Does anyone know how to get this working or has a better solution to push data from outside into an R Shiny application?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The client interacting with your shiny application needs to handle javascript/websockets which to my knowledge the `urllib2` library does not.

Comment: Shiny apps are client-server applications, so you need something that runs Javascript. A potential candidate is https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape Another potential solution http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I solved my problem by using httpuv and creating a websocket server. Example to be found here: https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv/blob/master/demo/daemon-echo.R

Comment: @tanktoo This is a very interesting approach. If you can write your solution as an answer it will help others in the future.

Comment: @warmoverflow done

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283736/r-shiny-rest-api-communication/71064046#71064046) a related topic can be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My complete solution using websockets with httpuv:

```
library(httpuv)
startWSServer <- function(){
   if(exists('server')){
      stopDaemonizedServer(server)
   }
   app <- list(
      onWSOpen = function(ws) {
         ws$onMessage(function(binary, message) {
            #handle your message, for example save it somewhere 
            #accessible by Shiny application, here it is just printed
            print(message)
            ws$send("message received")
         })
      }
   )
   server <<- startDaemonizedServer("0.0.0.0", 9454, app)
}

stopWSServer <- function(){
   stopDaemonizedServer(server)
   server <<- NULL
}
```

Hope this helps ;)