# How can I pull data on my R shiny server using REST API

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, rstudio-server

I have developed a relatively simply R shiny app that does the following:

1. I input a txt file.
2. The txt file is processed.
3. A new object is created: timestamp + a number.
   I save it in my sql database for instance or I save it as a .txt on my server.

I want to configure an API such as on a specific request it would pull the new object through the R shiny server. I believe I could use plumber but that means to run 2 servers and somehow coordinate the data flow.
Is there a simple solution such as I could get the data using my R shiny server using an api tool and a simple GET?

Thank you

Comment: Please check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283736/r-shiny-rest-api-communication/71064046#71064046) which is showing how to handle POST requests directly in `shiny`.