# Call a second shiny app within a first shiny app using an actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, shinyml

I have a simple `shiny` app and within RStudio I want to call a second `shiny` app with the use of an `actionbutton()`. Im trying to store `runApp()` of second app in an R script and execute this script as a separate R Studio Job. This will start the second shiny app in a new session without stopping the first one.

**my initial app**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyML)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("ftype","Choose file type",choices = c("csv","xlsx","xls"),selected = "csv"),
      
      actionButton("launch_app", "Launch second Shiny App")
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$launch_app, {
    rstudioapi::jobRunScript(path = "C:/Users/User/Documents/Deniz3/script.R")
  })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**the script from which I call the 2nd shiny app**

```
#script.r
    shiny::runApp("C:/Users/User/Documents/Deniz3/shinyML-master/R/shinyML_classification.R", launch.browser = TRUE, port = 875)
```

and the 2nd shiny app script  can be downloaded [shinyML_classification.r](https://github.com/JeanBertinR/shinyML/tree/master/R)

the error I get when I hit the `actionButton()` is `Error in func(fname, ...) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.`

You can easily see the second app if you run

```
install.packages("shinyML")

library(shinyML)

# An example of classification task  
shinyML_classification(data = iris,y = "Species",framework = "h2o")
```

Comment: I think it'd be far simpler for you to have that second app as a full deployed shiny app, and go to it with a link, perhaps `shiny::tags$a(href="https://shinyapps.io/my-other-app", target="_blank")`, optionally adding components to the URL to deal with user parameters from the current app (perhaps using [bookmarking](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-bookmark.html)).

Comment: the full scenario is to upload a file in the 1st app, process it and then pass it to the 2nd with the actionbutton which will alutomatically display the 2nd app

Comment: but the data that the 2nd app gets as input will not be the same everytime library(shinyML)

# An example of classification task  
shinyML_classification(data = iris,y = "Species",framework = "h2o")

Comment: Passing largish objects between different R processes is not trivial. Perhaps use a shared directory and an unambiguous and difficult-to-conflict file naming convention: save the model from app1 into (say) `"path/to/1706716655_8544.rds"`, a filename derived from `as.numeric(Sys.time())` and `Sys.getpid()`, and then pass that filename to app2.

Comment: Use `pins` package to pin the data from first app to pins::board_connect().  Second app should read that pinned data. You can go to the second app from the first app using a link as suggested by @r2evans.

Comment: can you post an example of this as an answer?

Comment: This could be done using an API. Please check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283736/r-shiny-rest-api-communication/71064046#71064046).

Comment: install.packages("shinyML")

library(shinyML)
# An example of classification task  
shinyML_classification(data = iris,y = "Species",framework = "h2o")this line creates a shiny app. how could I call it via this API through a basic initial shiny app? @ismirsehregal